# CSS :hover on other element?

Tags: css, hover

Short question: Why does the `background-color` of `.b` does not change when I hover? `.a`?

**CSS**

```css
.a {
    color: red;
}

.b {
    color: orange;
}

.a:hover .b {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="a">AAAA</div>
    <div class ="b">BBBB</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2NEgt/

Comment: For your CSS code to work, the second div should be embedded within the first one.

Comment: `.b` would have to be a child of `.a` for this to work

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to have `.a:hover + .b` instead of `.a:hover .b`

`.a:hover .b` would work for a structure like

```
<div class="a">AAAA
  <div class ="b">BBBB</div>
</div>
```

If at some point you'll need to have some elements between .a and .b, then you'll need to use `.a:hover ~ .b`, which works for *all siblings of `.a` coming after it*, not just the next one.

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/EajKf/

Answer (score 6):

Can you not do something like `a:hover + b`? see http://meyerweb.com/eric/articles/webrev/200007a.html

Answer (score 6):

You can use + selector

```css
.a:hover + .b {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

to apply the css for sibling element, or

```css
.a:hover > .b {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

for nested class.

Answer (score 3):

because .b isn't a child of .a, so that selector isn't finding anything. Use javascript to do what you want to do there.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you can do.

Either change your HTML to make `.b` a child of `.a`

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="a">AAAA
       <div class ="b">BBBB</div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

OR

Change your css to use the adjacent selector

```css
.a:hover + .b {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

no js needed http://jsfiddle.net/2NEgt/3/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change a sibling's style when an event occurs on a different element. It's out of the context of CSS.

Use JavaScript to achieve this, for example:

```
var wrap = document.getElementById("wrap");
var aDiv = wrap.getElementsByClassName("a")[0];
var bDiv = wrap.getElementsByClassName("b")[0];
aDiv.onmouseover = function() {
    bDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
};
aDiv.onmouseout = function() {
    bDiv.style.backgroundColor = "white";
};
```

Comment: Actually, you can, using sibling selector `.a:hover + .b` or `.a:hover ~ .b`

Comment: i dont know why this has been upvoted as what @Ana has said is true

Answer (score 0):

try to understanding this example:
html code

```
<p>Hover over 1 and 3 gets styled.</p>
<div id="one" class="box">1</div>
<div id="two" class="box">2</div>
<div id="three" class="box">3</div>
```

```
<!--css-->
#one:hover ~ #three{
background-color: black;
color: white;
}
.box {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
margin: 5px;
outline: 1px solid black;
text-align: center;
width: 30px;
}
```

when you hover on the box 1 than the box 3 will get black color

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is a good and easy solution:

**html:**

```
<div class="a">AAA</div>
<div class="b">BBB</div>
```

**script:**
Put this script into your html if you want. That's all.

```
<script>
      $(".a").mouseover(function(){
        $(".b").css("color", "blue"); 
      });
      $(".a").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".b").css("color", "red");
      });
</script>
```