# Target multiple elements on hover css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple elements I'm already targeting the hover class and that works it's showing the text and the icon, however, I need to change the `opacity` of the image as well so that shows when hovering over the text.

So I need both the text, icon and image to show all at the same time.

I've attempted this using CSS but if JS or jQuery is needed then a solution would be spot on.

Here is my code so far:

```css
.features.desktop.highly-interactive.text {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 258 px;
  }

  .features.desktop.highly-interactive.text h2 {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  .features.desktop.highly-interactive.hover {
    padding-top: 30 px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .features.desktop.highly-interactive.hover: hover {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <section class="inner_content">
    <img src="./images/product-circle.svg" width="667">
    <img src="./images/product-features-default.png" alt="PlayOctobo plush" class="main-image">

    <a href="https://shop.trycelery.com/page/5bf8be5e33ce8313001185de" target="_blank" class="btn">Pre-Order Now</a>

    <div class="images">
      <img src="./images/HIImage.png" alt="Highly interactive" class="highly-interactive">
    </div>

    <section class="highly-interactive">
      <section class="text">
        <h2>Highly Interactive</h2>

        <section class="hover">
          <img src="./images/HIIcon.svg" class="icon">
          <span>8 separate sensor arrays invisibly integrated into Octobo’s arms and body, responsive LED lighting, and the touchscreen itself</span>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand. I get that you want the text, icon, and image to all display at once, but what do you want to be hovered over for these to display? What will be the hovered element?

Comment: @JackBashford On hover yes, so once I hover over `highly-interactive` the text, icon and image in the `images` class should show.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS :hover on other element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507481/css-hover-on-other-element)

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You can apply hover effects on **parent**, **children** and **siblings**

> .parent .child {} 
>  .child ~ .siblings {}

Comment: Might want to make a wrapper around the entire component and then use that wrapper to hover on and apply affect to any of its children. That usually works

Answer (score 0):

you can use the jquery code to make the class of the images to show on hover.

```
$(".highly-interactive").mouseover(function(){
    $(".images").show();
  });
```

First do make this class to hide on DOM load.

```
window.load=function(){
$(".images").show();
}
```

and then load the script of mouseover to show only when it is hover.